# Dialog changes the orientation by itself. How to fix the orientation of a dialog to landscape

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialog

I am showing a custom dialog in an activity of which the orientation is set to landscape. But the orientation is getting changed to portrait mode from the inital landscape(only the dialog, below activity remains in landscape mode). This is happening without any outside action like tilting the tablet or something.

I could not find any help in fixing the orientation of dialog anywhere.

Any ideas?

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert);
mDialog.show();
```

This is the code used for showing the dialog.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:background="@drawable/alert_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    ------------------------------
    ---------------------------
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the xml element parent tag used.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also facing the same issue. How to fix the orientation of the dialog to portrait?

Answer (score 1):

If you are  using an Activity as a dialog then you can set

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

in your manifest file.

If you are using custom dialog then you can use

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

before you use setContentView(); method.

Comment: No. Its not an activity.